# High request sent time

Tags: node.js, rest

What could be the cause for high Request Sent time?

1)I checked the request payload size which in my case is large approximately (2.5 MB on disk)

2)How can I decrease this time?

3)Do I have to implement compression on frontend and then decompress on the server ? (NodeJs)

4)My use case doesn't allow using streams.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the reason for such high Request Sent time is a large payload size.

> How can I decrease this time?

Obviously, you can decrease the payload size. Either just try to remove some parts from it if possible or try to minimize it or compress it as you suggested yourself.

Also, check that your server has a good download speed.

> My use case doesn't allow using streams.

You already send a stream of bytes when sending a payload to the server so not sure what you mean by that.